# onPause() or onStop()

Tags: java, android, timer

This isn't working the way I expected. However, the way I expect it to work is probably wrong.

I have an application that implements a Countdown timer. When the back button on the android phone is clicked the user is navigated back to the main screen. However, the countdown timer still runs in the background. I can tell as it performs a beer at certain intervals.

I thought if I implemented `onPause()` I would be able to call `countdowntimer.cancel()`. And it would cancel the count down timer when the user exits the activity via the back button. However, the application fails instead.

I have also tried a similar approach with `onStop()` but it just doesn't work.

I don't have my code with me at the moment, it's just on my mind. Also sorry if there are any mistakes on this post, I have written it on my phone.

Comment: It performs a beer? Cool!

Comment: In what way does it fail? Some code and logs would help.

Comment: if you cancel a timer in onPause() it will cancel the timer. If activtiy resumes you must schedule your time again. If the app fails there must be some exception or error in logcat. pls paste the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**onPause()** call when *one Activity* transfer control to *another Activity*, and **onStop()** method call when *Activity* in **finish** mode.

Comment: what happens during screenlock? orientation change

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
movetasktoback(true);//in the onbackpressed
```

Then use the:

```
countdowntimer.cancel();// in onpause
```

After that you can call `finish()` in `onpause()`.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you call countdowntimer.cancel() when back key is pressed
you can override back click like

```
@Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
         if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
             countdowntimer.cancel();
         }

         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
     }
```